# Running into error when trying to deploy Superset in a Docker contenarized enviroment

Tags: business-intelligence, apache-superset

We would like to deploy Superset in a Docker contenarized enviroment, our DevOps team trying to make it work for days but without success.

Now they are getting this message ( i attach the full log):
superset pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'cryptography<40,>=39.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by apache-superset
. Does anyone have any idea for this kind of problem ?
We would like to use Superset for our product and it works super cool in our VMs but of course that's not a solution for production where we need HA, LDAP, etc...
Thank you for your answers in advance and have a nice day!

```
Init Step 1/4 [Starting] -- Applying DB migrations


######################################################################

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 568, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 886, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 777, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (cryptography 38.0.4 (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages), Requirement.parse('cryptography<40,>=39.0.1'), {'apache-superset'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/superset", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('apache-superset', 'console_scripts', 'superset')())
  File "/usr/local/bin/superset", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 86, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/superset/cli/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    from superset.cli.lib import normalize_token
  File "/app/superset/cli/lib.py", line 20, in <module>
    from superset import config
  File "/app/superset/config.py", line 38, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3243, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3226, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3255, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 570, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 772, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'cryptography<40,>=39.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by apache-superset
[tomi@alfa superset]$ 
[tomi@alfa superset]$ git branch
* (HEAD detached at 2.1.0)
  master
```